# Find string packet in decrypted data with wireshark/tshark

Tags: networking, wireshark, forensics, decryption

I am analysing a capture of encrypted traffic with wireshark. I have decrypted the traffic with the proper passphrase in wireshark and I can see the decrypted data of each frame.

The point is that if I search a packet with a certain string I cannot find it. Even though I have the certainty the string is decrypted given that I can see such data in the decrypted data of a frame.

I have already tried to search in packet bytes/list/details with string option and I also have searched by hexvalue without success.

A workaround that came into my mind that consists of using tshark to decrypt the traffic and make an hexdump to a text file. After that, use grep to find the string. However, this is not a nice approach.

How would you find a string with wireshark on a decrypted traffic capture?

Comment: Can you give more detail about why the usual search feature doesn't work?

Comment: This is not a security question. This appears to be a Wireshark use question.

Comment: It looks like it only searches on the encrypted data even though the data is shown in both ways (encrypted and decrypted). For example, I am able to find strings or hexvalues that are available in the encrypted data.

Comment: According to what you say this may be a bug. The right place to ask the question on on the [wireshark forums](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/).

Answer (score 1):

The **find** feature only works on dissected fields, and the decrypted data, if not handed to a dissector for interpretation, won't have any dissected fields.  So, you can either write a dissector for the decrypted data or you should at least be able to use a display filter such as, `data contains "some string"` to find the packets containing your string of interest.